# FFMPEG x265 encoding wrong settings for some sources

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding

I am trying to encode a file with this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i "source.mp4" -c:v libx265 -preset slow -crf 23.8 -vf scale=1920:-1:flags=lanczos -x265-params ref=6:bframes=5:no-sao=1:no-strong-intra-smoothing=1:cutree=0:aq-mode=3:deblock=-1,-1:rskip=0:rc-lookahead=80:subme=1:numa-pools=16:frame-threads=4 -c:a copy -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

Some files are coming back with very different encoding setting. Even the CRF is wrong in Mediainfo. I am seeing a warning when this happens that says:

```
[mp4 @ 00000148a5247040] track 1: codec frame size is not set
```

I googled this and no one seems to mention this warning as causing a problem.

I am using a fairly recent build: `ffmpeg version 2021-10-03-git-2761a7403b-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers`
built with gcc 10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project).

```
SOURCE MEDIAINFO:

    Video
    ID : 1
    Format : AVC
    Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
    Format profile : High@L5.1
    Format settings : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
    Format settings, CABAC : Yes
    Format settings, Reference frames : 4 frames
    Codec ID : avc1
    Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding
    Duration : 32 min 43 s
    Bit rate : 20.5 Mb/s
    Width : 3 840 pixels
    Height : 2 160 pixels
    Display aspect ratio : 16:9
    Frame rate mode : Constant
    Frame rate : 25.000 FPS
    Color space : YUV
    Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
    Bit depth : 8 bits
    Scan type : Progressive
    Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.099
    Stream size : 4.69 GiB (100%)
    Writing library : x264 core 157 r2969 d4099dd
    Encoding settings : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=8 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=50 / keyint_min=5 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=25.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
    Language : English
    Codec configuration box : avcC
```

```
X265 OUTPUT MEDIAINFO:

    Video
    ID : 1
    Format : HEVC
    Format/Info : High Efficiency Video Coding
    Format profile : Main@L4@Main
    Codec ID : hev1
    Codec ID/Info : High Efficiency Video Coding
    Duration : 32 min 43 s
    Bit rate : 5 186 kb/s
    Width : 1 920 pixels
    Height : 1 080 pixels
    Display aspect ratio : 16:9
    Frame rate mode : Constant
    Frame rate : 25.000 FPS
    Color space : YUV
    Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0 (Type 0)
    Bit depth : 8 bits
    Scan type : Progressive
    Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.100
    Stream size : 1.19 GiB (100%)
    Encoding settings : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=8 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=50 / keyint_min=5 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=25.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
    Language : English
    Color range : Limited
    Codec configuration box : hvcC
```

The output encoding settings seem to match the source instead of my encoder settings. Some files encode fine with the exact same settings, but don't have the warning message "codec frame size is not set". I have changed settings around quite a few times and same result for the problem files. If it only happened once I would think a problem with the source but it has happened to 2 of the last 4 files I encoded, so I must be missing something. It might just be incorrect metadata in the output, but I don't know for sure. This is not happening in Handbrake, I tried a different build of FFMPEG same problem.

Comment: This happens even if I simply encode with
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -c:v libx265 -preset veryfast -crf 23.8 -c:a copy output.mp4

Comment: In fact one of your user unregistered SEI has 8x8dct=1 and other does not. But yeah, this is a bug that was fixed in https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/7dfc3cc713ea0dbe7aeedcc2a272a5382a36dbcd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a change in Aug 2021 where the libx265 will convey any SEI data in the pre-encode input frames to the encoded packets. This includes encoding settings, if any were stored, from the source. The [change](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/1f58503013720) was motivated by the need to support the conveyance of other types of SEI data.

This only affects the stored string. The encoder parameters are what the user set.

Open a [bug ticket](https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html) with the needed info.

Comment: I actually saw that change request while research my issue, isn't there an option to bypass this behavior? I guess I can just get an older build.

Comment: So rolling back to an earlier build resolved the issue, thanks.  This was driving me crazy, I lost a day trying to figure it out.